# Where to put code for coding Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types

I’m wondering what is the best place to put the php code for defining custom post types.

Looks like theme functions.php is a big no-no because CPT are lost when switching theme

Wordpress codex recommends defining CPTs inside a plugin code

Some authors of tutorials I read recommend to define CPTs in a mu-plugin, which cannot be accidentally deactivated. 
That sounds like a great idea to me

Anyway, is there a wordpress (or Wordpress developer community) best practice?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think that this choice really depends on the project. If a post type is intrinsically linked to the theme. Maybe your theme will have a js and css bundle that includes post type features.  In this case it is better to define it immediately in this one. But it really depends on the project and how the code is organized. There is no "THE right method".

But if the custom post type brings new features that may potentially need to be deleted (for example: an event list on a site). It is better to define them in a plugin or mu-plugin.

Comment: Could you elaborate this part please “Maybe your theme will have a js and css bundle that includes post type features”? It’s really difficult for me to think about a reasonable case where custom post types (user facing) are strictly connected to the theme and will loose meaning when switching themes. Thanks!

Comment: My opinion: CPT are datas so, yes, in theory this is not part of the theme. But in the end it will be necessary to design these "datas"... in the theme.  If you change the theme you will have to redesign these custom post type in any case. So in order to avoid scattering the code I prefer to define the custom post type in the theme, it is a personal opinion. 
That said, while writing this comment I came across this [wpbeginner post](https://www.wpbeginner.com/opinion/wordpress-custom-post-types-debate-functions-php-or-plugins/) that contradicts me, it is also an interesting opinion.

Comment: Robin, your point of wiew is respectable. Anyway I think Separation of Concerns is a really important concept, even in wordpress based web development. Having learned my lessons (sometimes the hard way), I do my best to stick to best practices